# Python win32api GetFileAttributes

Tags: python, winapi

I'm receiving the following error while trying to grab File Permissions/attributes. I haven't been able to find anything that has helped. Any idea would be great.

> pywintypes.error: (123, 'GetFileAttributes', 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.')

Here is the code I'm using.

```
def getfileinfo(dir, ignoreddirs):
""" Loops through the directory and sub directories to get File Attributre Info """
print("Starting File Checks.")
for dirName, subDirList, fileList in os.walk(dir):
    # lets remove the ignored dirs from the subDirList
    for i in range(len(subDirList)):
        for x in range(len(ignoreddirs)):
            if subDirList[i] == ignoreddirs[x]:
                del subDirList[i]
    # Lets continue looping through
    print("We are in: %s" % dirName)

    for fname in fileList:
        print("We are checking file %s" % fname)
        # lets join the dir, dirname and filename
        file = dir + dirName + "\\" + fname
        print(file)
        # use win32api to get the Attributes
        att = win32api.GetFileAttributes(file)
        print("Attributes for this file is: " + att)
```

Here is the exact copy from the terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/yyy/main.py", line 26, in <module>
start()
File "C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/yyy/main.py", line 19, in start
getfileinfo(dir, ignoreddirs)
File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\yyy\permissionchecker.py", line 29, in  getfileinfo
att = win32api.GetFileAttributes(file)
pywintypes.error: (123, 'GetFileAttributes', 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.')
Starting File Checks.
We are in: C:\Users\crzyo\Desktop\EcoPC_0.4.2
We are checking file Eco.exe
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\EcoPC_0.4.2C:\Users\crzyo\Desktop\EcoPC_0.4.2\Eco.exe
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the last line on the traceback (or first depending on how you look at it). Your `dir` and `dirName` variables appear to return the same string. You're concatenating the same string twice plus the file name.